# Maclaurin series for EXPONENTS

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program that calculates the Maclaurin series for EXPONENTS and at each step outputs the value of the calculation error using the Maclaurin series (the module of the difference between values ​​obtained using the Maclaurin series and using a function from the math package)

Comment: More info or code please?